# set download attribute on dynamically displayed image

Tags: javascript, html, image, download

I'm displaying a long list of images from a site on a page with the below code. Id like to be able to use the download `HTML5` attribute so that click each image will download it.

Here's what I've tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i<arlnData.d.length;i++) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "https://images.website.com/airvendors/airlines_"+arlnData.d[i].Code+".gif"; 
        img.download ="my image"; 

        //also tried: 
        //img.src = "https://images.website.com/airvendors/airlines_"+arlnData.d[i].Code+".gif";
        document.body.appendChild(img);

        var imageCellspace=document.createElement('br');
        document.body.appendChild(imageCellspace);
}
```

Images are displayed fine but clicking to download doesnt work.

What is the proper syntax here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this:

```
for (var i = 0; i<arlnData.d.length;i++) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "https://images.website.com/airvendors/airlines_"+arlnData.d[i].Code+".gif"; 

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = img.src;
        a.download = 'image.gif';

        a.appendChild(img);

        document.body.appendChild(a);

        var imageCellspace=document.createElement('br');
        document.body.appendChild(imageCellspace);
}
```

The `download` attribute is for `a`, not for `img`. Check the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download).

Comment: Ah, needed the link, perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `<img>` on a `<a>`, as the `download` attribute is only for anchors.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "https://images.website.com/airvendors/airlines_"+arlnData.d[i].Code+".gif"; 

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = img.src;
a.download = "My image name";

a.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

[See MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) !